# Editing the GPT in MBR

Tags: partitioning, mbr

In the master boot record of every computer there is a global partition table that contains the information about the disk partitions .

This partitions will be read by the OS's going to be installed in the system where they will try to detect the file systems they support in this partition and if any such file-system  is there then it will be able to access that partition .

Now here I am speaking of partition as a physical entity . So , suppose I want to change the  number of partitions on my disk or reduce the number of partitions by one .  Then how to do it ? Will it be a simple edition of the GPT of the MBR or there is more to it ?

Comment: Your question does not make sense.  You are mixing up concepts between MBR and GPT which are independant partitiong schemas.

Comment: You used a phrase "global partition table" and *maybe* you refer to it as GPT. The common meaning of GPT is [GUID Partition Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) though. There are few incorrect assumptions in your question. Take "the master boot record of every computer". MBR does not belong to a computer but to a block device; not even to every block device – e.g. you can have a filesystem on the entire device ("superfloppy").

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski : What I meant by GPT is what lies just before magic two bytes in the MBR .I guess GUID partition table means the same thing .Isn't it so ?

Comment: @Ramhound : My bad I was actually refering to the content in MBR just above the magic two bytes .

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski : Could you write a bit more on the point "MBR does not belong to a computer but to a block device " .. What exactly do you mean by a block device?

Comment: HDD, SSD, USB pendrive, SD card, etc.; or even a file (see [loop device](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_device)).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski : So anyone of them can contain a bootable sector right ? Now what about the table of partitions just before the magic two byte signature in this bootable sectors ? They will contain the details of the memory layout of the device itself ,right ?

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski : My new question is about how to  control which bootable sector to choose , could you share your valuable insights there ?

Comment: "anyone of them can contain a bootable sector, right?" – Right. – "table of partitions […] will contain the details of the memory layout of the device itself, right?" – Right. – "how to control which bootable sector to choose?" – By a proper setting in BIOS or UEFI; also a bootloader like GRUB loaded from one device can chainload bootcode from another device.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski : But for perennial chainloading or bootstrapping the original bootloader has to be changed right ?

Comment: Yes, some change has to be made to permanently alter the behavior. Please note that asking new and new questions in comments is not the right usage of any Stack Exchange site (unless the purpose is to clarify the main question; other users ask such questions, not the author of the main question obviously). If you have another question then: (1) Read [ask]. (2) Do research (e.g. to make sure you understand basic concepts like the difference between MBR and GPT; or maybe a similar question has been asked and answered). (3) [Ask a separate question](https://superuser.com/questions/ask).

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski: Actually went through few links on disk drives and all these terms but wanted to make everything fall into a structure where all the terms have clear definitions .  But the sources turned out to be confusing so asked this question . By the way , I had already posted one separate question . Thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0):

The first thing you **must** do is identify what type of boot system you have on the PC: The older, MBR; now sometimes called BIOS boot, schema, is a lot easier to deal with than the newer UEFI boot system on GPT formatted devices.

Go to my web page, [An Examination of The Microsoft® Windows™ 7, 8 and 10 GPT 'Protective' MBR and EFI Partitions](https://thestarman.pcministry.com/asm/mbr/GPT.htm), and look at the second picture on that page and following; which shows a few different ways to determine if your PC is the older MBR or newer UEFI/GPT schema.

[image: Annotated screenshot of Computer Management dialog]

If it's the older MBR type, there are many things you can do with your disk drive with a raw disk editor... some of which can mess up your system, but not as easily as a UEFI/GPT disk! Changing a single byte outside of the user space can make one of those disks completely non-bootable!!! It's happened to me a number of times this week when trying to set up a new PC using an MBR to GPT converted OS. So, without some fully tested procedures, do **not** attempt to make any changes to a UEFI/GPT disk!

If you have the older MBR schema, there's a lot of information on my website dealing with those types of OS boot records, etc. I'd recommend using Google to search with "site:pcministry.com" (without quotes) at the very end of your keyword search string.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any data rescue reasons, you have two safe options to deal with MBR and GPT:

1. GParted which will change MBR or GPT (or both) and move the data if it is needed.
2. `fdisk` on Linux system and `resize2fs` before or after the partitions change.

But if you don't worry about the data (it is backed up/does not exist on this drive) you can try to manually edit MBR or GPT and see how specific operating system sees the drive after the edit.

Surely there are many partition editing apps for Windows and Linux but I gave you the most safe and most convenient.